# android-Out of memory error

Tags: android, heap-memory

I'm developing an app which has lots of `ImageView`s in its `Activity`s, but the sum of their sizes is about 2 MB. when the user clicks on a button another `Activity` is going to be shown but the current one *restarts* and I can see the below error in logcat. what's wrong?!

```
12-06 17:53:07.224: E/dalvikvm-heap(3938): 7704000-byte external allocation too large for this process.
12-06 17:53:07.224: E/dalvikvm(3938): Out of memory: Heap Size=5895KB, Allocated=3283KB, Bitmap Size=22871KB, Limit=32768KB
12-06 17:53:07.224: E/dalvikvm(3938): Trim info: Footprint=5895KB, Allowed Footprint=5895KB, Trimmed=864KB
12-06 17:53:07.224: E/GraphicsJNI(3938): VM won't let us allocate 7704000 bytes
```

**UPDATE:** I'm also using lots of `Animations` on these images and playing a background music!

Comment: I guess the size of all (compressed) image files is 2MB. When an image file is decoded it takes up substantially more RAM. You should only decode and hold in RAM what you need to display at a time.

Comment: could you please explain more? for example I have declared 12 ImageViews in xml file of my first Activity. how can I remove them from RAM when the second Activity is going to be shown?

Comment: RAM = height * width * 4 bytes, file size is not relevant

Answer (score 1):

You mention that the sum of the image sizes is about 2mb.  Is this the disk size or actual memory size?  Note that when you load an image into memory it uses a lot more than the file saved to disk.

I have successfully used the library below to prevent issues with out of memory.

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: yes, I mentioned the disk size. I'm also using lots of `Animations` on these images and playing a background music!

Answer (score 0):

I think the Picasso library (http://square.github.io/picasso/) the best for image loading, it does caching and cleans after you